# Does the spell Owl's Wisdom confer other benefits from an increased Wisdom ability, as the other ability buff spells?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e

All five of the other spells that temporarily buff an ability score explicitly state that the creature gains the other benefits of having an increased ability score. Owl's Wisdom, curiously, does not; though, it does specifically note what it does *not* allow for Wisdom-based casters, and *does* explicitly benefit skill checks. So does the creature not gain an improved Willpower save, for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultimately, most of that text in the other ability-enhancing spells describing those details is reminder, to save you having to look up all the things that ability score does for you. That text isn't mandatory for you to get those benefits however—the **only** thing those spells actually do is enhance an ability score. Everything else described in them is just explaining some of the ramifications of having a higher score in that ability.

The only parts of those spells’ descriptions, beyond the enhancement bonus itself, that is actually necessary to spell out, is the other thing you note: exceptions. That is, since the spells increase a given ability score, which has all these other consequences, anything that **doesn’t** benefit from that increase needs to be called out. Otherwise, it’s something that depends on that score and that score just changed. So in order for the spell to not give Wisdom-based spellcasters bonus spells, *owl’s wisdom* needs to say that it doesn’t do that.

By the way, for clarity, Wisdom-based casters certainly can benefit from *owl’s wisdom*; they’re actually the ones who do the most. They do not get bonus spells for doing so, true, but since they should have have high Wisdom, it is likely that they have also focused on other things Wisdom can do, e.g. Wisdom skills. More importantly, the saving throw DC against their spells is also based on Wisdom, and that is often one of the most important numbers they can boost—and *owl’s wisdom* is one way to do that. (Ultimately, since *owl’s wisdom* doesn’t last very long, it’s somewhat awkward for that purpose, and by mid levels most Wisdom-based spellcasters will want a Wisdom-enhancing *headband* and then *owl’s wisdom* is pointless because they are both enhancement bonuses and therefore do not stack, but nonetheless if you’re casting *owl’s wisdom* this is one of the best things you get from it.)

Finally, in case you are unaware, Paizo made some effort to standardize this kind of thing, defining “temporary” and “permanent” boosts to ability scores and what you get from each kind of thing for each score. You can read about those under each score [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores/). If I remember the history of this correctly, this standardization developed after Pathfinder’s original release (it certainly wasn’t present in the D&D 3.5e material that Pathfinder’s based on), so early material (like the core ability-enhancing spells, which are taken near-verbatim from 3.5e) doesn’t directly reference it but it’s mostly pretty consistent, I believe.